# git pushes files that git diff does not show

Tags: git, github

When I run `git diff --stat --cached origin/master` in my local repository I see certain committed files ready to be pushed. However, when I try to `git push`, it tries to push also different files that do not appear using `diff` and that are too big for my remote repository.

What is going on here? Solutions?

Comment: `--cached` shows the files ready to be committed. Remove it to list the committed files different from `origin/master`.

Comment: I think you should have handled this one step prior.  When you were going to make the commit, you should have run `git status` and thoroughly checked what was about to go into that commit.

Comment: Removing `--cached` gives me the same results as with it.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR: you'll need to `git reset`

You probably want a `git reset --soft origin/master` followed by a `git commit`.  Be aware, however, that this kind of `git reset` is one of the more dangerous Git commands, in that it can *remove* commits.  Git is built around *adding new commits*, which never causes any older commits to go away and therefore means that no previous committed work is ever lost.  Since `git reset` *removes* commits—or at least, can remove them—it's possible to lose committed work this way.

#### Description

`git push` pushes *commits*, not files.

`git diff --cached origin/master` compares the commit selected by the name `origin/master` against the current contents of the index.  The index is not a commit, so this tells you nothing about what `git push` would push.

#### Things to know about the index and commits

The *index*—which has several additional names: it's also called the *staging area*, and sometimes the *cache*—is where you have Git build up all the files that will be in the *next* commit you will make.  Initially, the index contains all the same files as are in the *current commit*.  The current commit is the one you checked out when you ran `git checkout master` (note that I'm assuming that you ran `git checkout master`, based on the name `origin/master` in your question).

Now, each commit that you have in your repository contains files, probably quite a lot of files.  Each commit acts as a complete, mostly-standalone, snapshot of *all* the files that are in that commit.

If you commit something, then remove a file and commit again, the new commit is like the old commit except that it has one fewer files.

If you commit something, then change a file and `git add` to copy the changes into the index and `git commit`, the new commit is like the old commit, except that the file you changed is different in the new commit.

In other words, whenever you run `git commit`, your Git packages up whatever is in your index *right then*, and turns that into a new commit.  In general, these new commits simply *add on* to your existing commits.  If each commit had a single-letter name, instead of big ugly names like `a123456...`, we might draw them like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Adding a new commit picks the next letter, adding it on to the chain of commits and making your `master` point to the new commit just added:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

When used in this manner, Git only ever *adds new commits*.

#### Things to know about `git push`

When you run `git push`, your Git calls up some other Git.  Your Git and their Git have a conversation to find out what commits you have that they don't, that you would like to give to them.  Your Git then says something like: *Here are these commits I have that you don't.  When you're done looking at them, please set your own `master` branch to record commit #a123456... as the last commit on your own `master`, just like it's the last commit on my `master`, ok?*

The error you are getting is because when you send those commits and that request, *their* Git looks through those commits and decides that some file(s) in some of those commit(s) are too big.

This means that to make your `git push` succeed, you must stop sending them *those* commits, the ones that have big files.

#### This means you must somehow *remove* commits

Now, suppose their `origin/master` ends at commit `F` in the chain of commits:

```
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Suppose further that the big files that they're complaining about are in commit `G` and/or commit `H`.  If you *remove* those big files from your index, and run `git commit`, you get new commit `I` which no longer has those big files:

```
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

But now you run `git push origin master`, i.e., send them commits `G-H-I` and then ask them to set their `master` to point to commit `I`.  They inspect commits `G` and `H` and find that there are big files in them.  It doesn't matter that the big files are gone in commit `I`; what matters is that you're having your Git send the entire chain, `G-H-I`, and the big files are in the *earlier* commits.

What you need to do is somehow make a new commit that's *not* connected back to the `G-H` sequence, e.g., somehow make a commit that might look like this instead:

```
       J   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H--I   <-- ???
```

(I've assumed here that you went ahead and made commit `I`—if not, just pretend it's not there in the drawing.)  Once you have *this* sequence, you can have your Git call up their Git, send them `J`—which connects back to `F` but they *already have `F`*—and then ask them to set their `master` to point to commit `J`.  Since `J` *doesn't* have the big file(s), that will be OK and, with luck, will pass any other requirements they impose, and they'll take `J` and put it in their repository.

If you run `git reset --soft origin/master` while your `HEAD` is attached to `master` like this,<sup>1</sup> your Git will change your `master` to point to the *same commit* as your `origin/master`:

```
...--F   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       G--H--I   [abandoned]
```

At this point, the *entire chain of commits* "after" `origin/master` no longer have the name `master` letting you find them.  This is why they can now be removed.<sup>2</sup>  The `--soft` part of this command tells Git: *Don't touch the index or the work-tree.*  So your index and work-tree are still set up the way they were for commit `I`.

If you now run `git commit`, you will get a new commit whose *snapshot* is from the index, which we just noted is set up to match commit `I`.  This is what creates new commit `J`.  Git uses the *current* commit, which is `F`, as the parent for the new commit, so that `J` connects back to `F`:

```
       J   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--F   <-- origin/master
```

which is just what we wanted.

So, *now* we can run `git push origin master`, which has our Git call up their Git, transfer commit `J` to them, and ask them to set their `master` to point to the new commit `J` we just sent.  The other commits—*all* of them—never leave our own repository.  We'd best stop using them anyway, since they have those big files that we don't want committed, so all is probably correct at this point.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git has two modes: one where `HEAD` is "attached to" some branch like `master`, and one where `HEAD` is *detached*.  The detached HEAD mode is useful for building up some commits and then attaching a branch name to them, and is used internally by things like `git rebase`.  It's much more common to go around with your HEAD attached, though. :-)

<sup>2</sup>Git keeps them around for at least another 30 days by default, in case you goofed up, but they can be hard to *find* now that they have no handy branch name.

Comment: Awesome answer! It worked perfectly and I learned a lot. Thanks!